# Does average row length mysql affect its performance?

Tags: mysql, database

Should I be worried about keeping many columns in a single row? or is that non issue for performance?

Comment: Depends. Is the table already normalized? Are you denormalizing on purpose to speed up a specific query? Is there a specific query you are worried about?

It really depends on what you are trying to do but generally speaking, having a lot of columns is not an issue at all.

Comment: @cen what is normalized?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2):

Be (slightly) worried.  The larger the tow size, the fewer rows can fit on a page of disk, so performance will suffer as row length goes up.

But don't change your design early on to avoid long rows - do what's right then worry about it if it becomes a problem. Changing your design purely to avoid future "performance problems" would be *opimizing early", which is a deadly sin.

Comment: Problem is if issue arises it will be hard to migrate all data in a meaningful way :S

Comment: The cost of the work-around may exceed buying faster hardware

Answer (score 0):

How many is 'many'? If you have a lot of NULLs because that particular column isn't needed then it can be more efficient to normalise the database into more tables with less NULL data points. But it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: I have users column, which has profile data. This profile data indeed can be empty. So I'd better create user_meta table and than do join?

Comment: It depends on how many. NULL isn't that bad, but if you have 1 million rows of 200 columns where 100 of those are NULL in 90% of your rows then it's smarter to normalise it to reduce the size.

Comment: More like 20 columns and 10 NULL.

Comment: Nowhere near any performance hits on 20 columns. If they're predictably NULL for certain inputs, it can make sense to split those rows into a separate table by reducing it to something like one of the "normal forms" in database theory. More information: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2 tables to store user profilea.

1. full one
2. users_mem, stored in MySql memory with 6 cols: id, username, gender, chat? pbs?

the most queries do not need more than user ID and name/nickname and sometimes gender.

chat & pbs = If these cols is zero, I do not need to lookup in my heavy tables if the user has a new messages.

works perefect with heavy system.